# How do you prove a limit is indeterminate?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, proof-explanation

This is a question from a calculus 1 class and
I am studying in preparation for this class, so there are a lot of things I still dont know and might be unfamiliar with.

Define $f(x)$ as :

$f(x)\begin{cases} x^{ \frac{1}{3} } sin( \frac{1}{x} ) & x \neq  0\\0 & x = 0\end{cases} $

Show that $f(x)$ is continuous but not differentiable at $0$.

**What I did:**

First to prove that $f(x)$ is continuous:

$-|x^{\frac{1}{3}}|\leq x^{ \frac{1}{3} } sin( \frac{1}{x} ) \leq |x^{\frac{1}{3}}|$

$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}-|x^{\frac{1}{3}}| \leq \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}x^{ \frac{1}{3} } sin( \frac{1}{x} )\leq \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} |x^{\frac{1}{3}}| $

$0\leq lim_{x \rightarrow 0}x^{ \frac{1}{3} } sin( \frac{1}{x} ) \leq 0$

So by the Squeeze Theorem $lim_{x \rightarrow 0}x^{ \frac{1}{3} } sin( \frac{1}{x} )=0$ and  so $f(x)$ is continuous at $0$.

Now to prove that $f(x)$ does not have a derivative at $0$:

$lim_{h \rightarrow 0} {\frac{h^{ \frac{1}{3} }sin({\frac{1}{h}})}{h}}$ should not be solvable, but I dont know how to prove it. Wolfram Alpha says the left hand and right limits are also indeterminate so its not a matter of just showing they are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have$$\frac{h^{1/3}\sin\left(\frac1h\right)}h=\frac{\sin\left(\frac1h\right)}{h^{2/3}}.\tag1$$Now, if $h=\frac1{\pi/2+2n\pi}$, with $n\in\Bbb Z$, then $(1)=\left(\frac\pi2+2n\pi\right)^{2/3}\to\infty$. And if $h=\frac1{3\pi/2+2n\pi}$, with $n\in\Bbb Z$, then $(1)=-\left(\frac{3\pi}2+2n\pi\right)^{2/3}\to-\infty$. So, the limit $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h^{1/3}\sin\left(\frac1h\right)}h$ doesn't exist.